# Case Sensitive first Occurence highlight

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column which is case sensitive & have duplicates, i want to highlight the first occurrence of each value .

I have used the below formula to give numbers from 1 to n for the case sensitive duplicates,

```
=IF(EXACT(A$2:A$3564,A2),COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2))
```

This is working fine for almost all records but when i encounter records like below, it is not indicating the numbers correctly.

```
0031Y00004remsw_Alistair Laycock
0031Y00004remsW_Alistair Laycock
0031Y00004remsw_Alistair Laycock
0031Y00004remsW_Alistair Laycock
0031Y00004remtm_Alistair Laycock
0031Y00004remtM_Alistair Laycock
0031Y00004remtm_Alistair Laycock
0031Y00004remtM_Alistair Laycock
```

below is the result in such cases

```
0031Y00004remsw_Alistair Laycock     1
0031Y00004remsW_Alistair Laycock     2
0031Y00004remsw_Alistair Laycock     3
0031Y00004remsW_Alistair Laycock     4
0031Y00004remtm_Alistair Laycock     1
0031Y00004remtM_Alistair Laycock     2
0031Y00004remtm_Alistair Laycock     3
0031Y00004remtM_Alistair Laycock     4
```

The desired output is like below :-

```
0031Y00004remsw_Alistair Laycock     1
0031Y00004remsW_Alistair Laycock     1   'This being first Occurance with "w" 
                                          in capital'
0031Y00004remsw_Alistair Laycock     2   'This being second Occurance with "w" 
                                          in small'
0031Y00004remsW_Alistair Laycock     2
0031Y00004remtm_Alistair Laycock     1
0031Y00004remtM_Alistair Laycock     1
0031Y00004remtm_Alistair Laycock     2
0031Y00004remtM_Alistair Laycock     2
```

Any suggestions/help would be highly appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--EXACT(A2,$A$2:A2)))
```

[image]